# Spanish for 'clutch' as used in eSports?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, deportes

'**Clutch**' is a term that's been [used in classic sports](https://nba.nbcsports.com/2018/05/28/cavaliers-were-clutch-all-season-then-again-in-its-biggest-moment/) for some time, but nowadays it is more relevant than ever in eSports:

- [Swag's Clean Desert Eagle **Clutch** Against Some of NA's Best CS:GO Players](https://www.dexerto.com/news/swag-clean-desert-eagle-clutch-nas-best-csgo-players/38429)
- [Breaking down Skadoodle's 1v4 **clutch** vs. Astralis](https://vandal.elespanol.com/esports/articulos/4333/rush-da-la-vuelta-al-mundo-con-este-clutch-4k)
- [Rocket League Open Ends In **Clutch** Overtime Goal](https://compete.kotaku.com/rocket-league-open-ends-in-clutch-overtime-goal-1822493317)
- [Steel’s **clutch** vs coL gives Torqued its first qualifier spot at DreamHack Tours](https://dotesports.com/counter-strike/news/steel-clutch-vs-col-dh-tours-quals-2018-22614)
- ... etc.

Its meaning in this context is clear... kind of. As per the accepted answer in [this question back at Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177879/what-is-a-clutch-in-competitive-gaming-not-in-the-car-sense):

> Definitions of "[clutch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clutch)" (adjective):
>
> > 1. happening during a very important or critical time especially in a sports competition
> > 2. able to perform well in a very important or critical situation especially in a sports competition
>
> This term has since migrated to competitive gaming, where is used in similar situations, usually in professional gaming events where there is a lot at stake.

It is one of those words that is short and simple while at the same time it describes a very specific setting.
That's probably the reason why Spanish specialized media use 'clutch' *as-is*, like [here](https://esports.marca.com/csgo/giants-vence-g2-tras-cuatro-overtimes.html) and [here](https://vandal.elespanol.com/esports/articulos/4333/rush-da-la-vuelta-al-mundo-con-este-clutch-4k), instead of looking for a similar Spanish term. Even mainstream media like EL MUNDO shows some trouble picking a word for this concept:

> (...) eso que los americanos llaman **clutch**, digamos ser decisivo cuando el sol más calienta.
>
> <sub>[Source](http://www.elmundo.es/deportes/baloncesto/2018/05/29/5b0c59a9e2704ed5318b45f6.html)</sub>

Clearly we know how to define the word in Spanish, but **it'd be great if we could find a single word for it**.
How would you translate this concept to Spanish using just a couple words at most?

Comment: This is probably going to be one of those questions that have two answers: one for each definition of _clutch_. For the second one I'd use _temple_: "Fortaleza enérgica y valentía serena para afrontar las dificultades y los riesgos." But I'm sure there must be better options.

Comment: `remontada` maybe

Comment: Agree about `remontada`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native speaker and a eSports passionate, I think good translations could be *clave* or *decisivo* when used as an adjective.

For example:

> This play was started by a clutch save by SKT support Lee "Wolf" Jae-wan on top laner Heo "Huni" Seung-hoon

Could be translated to:

> Esta jugada se inició a partir de una salvada decisiva del soporte Lee "Wolf" Jae-wan sobre el carrilero superior Heo "Huni" Seung-hoon

Hope I've been helpful

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo.

Comment: No me gustaría poner remontada porque remontar es ir perdiendo y luego devolver la situación desfavorable y ganar. Puedes ser "clutch" incluso yendo empatado, p.e: SKT vs ROX en la semifinal del mundial del 2016 de LoL. Iban 2-2 pero SKT mantuvo la calma y ganó. "clutch" en el sentido de cold-minded podría traducirse como con cabeza fría, o de cabeza fría